# Intermittent slow frames on Android OpenGL ES 2.0

Tags: java, android, opengl-es-2.0

I'm getting some slow frames with OpenGL ES 2.0 on Android. Enough so that they are causing stuttering in the rendering.
I've put in some lines that output to System.err these two pieces of information:

1. Average draw time over the last 60 frames ("Avg draw time: 2")
2. A frame took over 10 ms to draw, g = GUI draw time, w = world draw time ("Slow frame!!! (29, g=27, w=2)")

I've posted some sample output below this question, showing random slow frames.

This happens even when nothing in the scene changes. What could be causing these intermittent slow frames? If I drill down even farther to time things and see if there's anything consistently slowing things down, I don't see anything. It just seems random.
The garbage collection only occurs twice in this sample output, so I wouldn't think GC would be the issue. What else could cause these frames to take so long from time to time?

```
11-09 13:42:53.768: W/System.err(25924): Avg draw time: 2
11-09 13:42:54.839: W/System.err(25924): Avg draw time: 2
11-09 13:42:55.860: W/System.err(25924): Avg draw time: 2
11-09 13:42:56.881: W/System.err(25924): Avg draw time: 2
11-09 13:42:57.442: D/dalvikvm(25924): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1715K, 62% free 3619K/9379K, paused 1ms+2ms
11-09 13:42:57.912: W/System.err(25924): Avg draw time: 2
11-09 13:42:58.273: W/System.err(25924): Slow frame!!! (29, g=27, w=2)
11-09 13:42:58.924: W/System.err(25924): Avg draw time: 3
11-09 13:42:59.014: W/System.err(25924): Slow frame!!! (19, g=2, w=17)
11-09 13:42:59.955: W/System.err(25924): Avg draw time: 4
11-09 13:43:00.075: W/System.err(25924): Slow frame!!! (28, g=25, w=3)
11-09 13:43:00.445: W/System.err(25924): Slow frame!!! (20, g=9, w=11)
11-09 13:43:01.026: W/System.err(25924): Avg draw time: 4
11-09 13:43:02.037: W/System.err(25924): Avg draw time: 4
11-09 13:43:02.197: W/System.err(25924): Slow frame!!! (16, g=14, w=2)
11-09 13:43:02.227: W/System.err(25924): Slow frame!!! (16, g=4, w=12)
11-09 13:43:03.088: W/System.err(25924): Avg draw time: 5
11-09 13:43:03.218: W/System.err(25924): Slow frame!!! (13, g=8, w=5)
11-09 13:43:03.308: W/System.err(25924): Slow frame!!! (22, g=16, w=6)
11-09 13:43:03.318: W/System.err(25924): Slow frame!!! (14, g=10, w=4)
11-09 13:43:03.348: W/System.err(25924): Slow frame!!! (11, g=8, w=3)
11-09 13:43:04.109: W/System.err(25924): Avg draw time: 4
11-09 13:43:05.030: W/System.err(25924): Slow frame!!! (31, g=29, w=2)
11-09 13:43:05.060: W/System.err(25924): Slow frame!!! (11, g=3, w=8)
11-09 13:43:05.070: W/System.err(25924): Slow frame!!! (15, g=11, w=3)
11-09 13:43:05.150: W/System.err(25924): Avg draw time: 4
11-09 13:43:06.191: W/System.err(25924): Avg draw time: 2
11-09 13:43:07.202: W/System.err(25924): Avg draw time: 1
11-09 13:43:08.243: W/System.err(25924): Avg draw time: 3
11-09 13:43:09.275: W/System.err(25924): Avg draw time: 4
11-09 13:43:09.965: W/System.err(25924): Slow frame!!! (29, g=28, w=1)
11-09 13:43:10.025: D/dalvikvm(25924): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1721K, 62% free 3625K/9379K, paused 3ms+4ms
11-09 13:43:10.296: W/System.err(25924): Avg draw time: 4
11-09 13:43:10.736: W/System.err(25924): Slow frame!!! (14, g=11, w=2)
11-09 13:43:10.756: W/System.err(25924): Slow frame!!! (14, g=3, w=11)
11-09 13:43:10.776: W/System.err(25924): Slow frame!!! (14, g=1, w=13)
11-09 13:43:11.307: W/System.err(25924): Avg draw time: 4
11-09 13:43:11.337: W/System.err(25924): Slow frame!!! (17, g=3, w=14)
11-09 13:43:11.357: W/System.err(25924): Slow frame!!! (14, g=3, w=11)
11-09 13:43:11.387: W/System.err(25924): Slow frame!!! (12, g=2, w=10)
11-09 13:43:11.797: W/System.err(25924): Slow frame!!! (17, g=14, w=3)
11-09 13:43:12.328: W/System.err(25924): Avg draw time: 3
11-09 13:43:13.319: W/System.err(25924): Slow frame!!! (19, g=3, w=16)
11-09 13:43:13.349: W/System.err(25924): Avg draw time: 5
11-09 13:43:13.379: W/System.err(25924): Slow frame!!! (14, g=10, w=4)
11-09 13:43:13.970: W/System.err(25924): Slow frame!!! (14, g=11, w=3)
11-09 13:43:14.410: W/System.err(25924): Avg draw time: 4
11-09 13:43:15.061: W/System.err(25924): Slow frame!!! (12, g=9, w=2)
11-09 13:43:15.081: W/System.err(25924): Slow frame!!! (13, g=3, w=10)
11-09 13:43:15.111: W/System.err(25924): Slow frame!!! (23, g=16, w=6)
11-09 13:43:15.461: W/System.err(25924): Avg draw time: 5
11-09 13:43:16.142: W/System.err(25924): Slow frame!!! (18, g=3, w=15)
11-09 13:43:16.162: W/System.err(25924): Slow frame!!! (14, g=11, w=3)
11-09 13:43:16.482: W/System.err(25924): Avg draw time: 5
11-09 13:43:17.223: W/System.err(25924): Slow frame!!! (17, g=14, w=3)
11-09 13:43:17.243: W/System.err(25924): Slow frame!!! (15, g=4, w=11)
11-09 13:43:17.503: W/System.err(25924): Avg draw time: 5
11-09 13:43:18.054: W/System.err(25924): Slow frame!!! (17, g=9, w=8)
```

Comment: what android version do you use?

Comment: I've been testing on an HTC One X running Android 4.0.4

Comment: Did you ever get to the bottom of this @Brad?  I've having the exact same problem, most frames come in well under 16.667ms, but randomly, one comes along that takes 20-30 and it results in 'choppy' animation.  Even stripping the scene down to just one simple Quad - the problem persists.  Had this issue for ages and never been able to get to the bottom of why it happens - cheers.